# Nifi JSON regular expression

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I am using convert AvroToJson processor to convert avro to json and then split json with expression $.* to break json array to individual record.

It is failing in case there is single element in json and not an array.

Can someone help with regular expression to support both array and single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try using ConvertRecord processor with an AvroReader and JsonWriter, then use SplitRecord with a record count of 1.

It may also be possible to avoid splitting to individual records. Typically that is done in order to manipulate each record, but with the record processors you can typically manipulate them in place, thus improving performance significantly by not splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have nothing to split in a single element. If you want to avoid failure on single elements, you can use `ConvertRecord` instead of `ConvertAvroToJson`.

The difference is, that `ConvertRecord` will provide you the attribute `record.count` which tells you how many records are included in this FlowFile(and also a more generic flow).

This will allow you to put a middle processor(`RouteOnAttribute`) between `ConvertRecord` and `SplitJSON`.

So you can config it as such:

> Routing Strategy=Route to 'matched' if all match
>
> match(dynamic property)=${record.count:equals(1)}

Then, transfer connect `matched` relationship to the processor that is placed after your `SplitJSON`, and connect `unmatched` to your `SplitJSON` processor. 
That way, if there's a single record(which shouldn't need any splitting), it will avoid the processor `SplitJSON`.